# Tooltip changes plot and displays plot in tooltip, but I just want the plot to change

Tags: tableau-api

I am working in Tableau and I have a plot that updates based on hover over a tree map by adding the sheet that updates to the tooltip. However, I find it redundant to have both the updated plot and tooltip displaying, but when I disable the tooltip the plot no longer updates. Is it possible to have the plot update with hover AND disable the tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set this up separately using "Actions". If you are not familiar with actions, the below link would be helpful:

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions_dashboards.htm